# selecting radio button in ajax

Tags: jquery

how to select radio button automatically in ajax?

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/CVEvaluation/GetResultData',
            type: "GET",
            data: { id: evalcriteria },
            success: function (data) {
                // put result of action into element with class "result"
                $("#textfield15").val(data.Column5);
                $("#textfield16").val(data.Column4);
                $("#textfield17").val(data.Column3);
                $("#textfield18").val(data.Column2);
                $("#textfield19").val(data.Column1);
                $("#textfield20").val(data.Total);

            },
            error: function () {
            }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like

```
$('input:radio[value="' + data.x + '"]').prop('checked', true)
```

Comment: thank u for reply but i have tried the same but its not working.

Comment: can you share the html for radio buttons and the `data` returned by server

Comment: <th width="189" valign="top" scope="col"><div align="center">
            <div align="center">
               @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.grade_index, "A+",new { @id = "gradeindex1" }) when text box value have some value this radio button should get selected like this there are some  range of values through which respective radio button will get selected and value of textbox is from Json result

Comment: Textbox Ranges will be like 55 to 45,45 to 35,35 to 25,25 to 15 if it satisfy the first range then the first radio button should get selected

Comment: what will be the `value` attribute of the radios buttons